# xpages passing the UNID to other field

Tags: xpages

I have an input field:

```
   <xp:inputText value="#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}" id="txt_UNID1"></xp:inputText>
```

The field   `txt_UNID` is computed having the value: `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)`.

What I noticed is that even I just compose the xpage containing the document content the inputText already contains some UNID even if the xpage containing the doc content wasn't saved.

There is a button which is showing a dialog containing a field. I want this field to have the value of `txt_UNID`

```
Cdoc.save(); // I must save first the Cdoc datasource ?
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()
```

And the code for the field:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{Pdoc.txt_CompanieUNID}"
id="txt_CompanieUNID1" defaultValue="#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}">
</xp:inputText>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether or not you must first save the document in order to get the UNID, my answer is yes.  In my tests, the UNID has changed from a new document to a freshly saved document.  So, yes if the current document is new, save before getting the UNID.  At least when it was a NotesXspDocument.

I also generally use JavaScript for this,

```
cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalId();
```

Otherwise, I am unsure what you are asking.

Comment: so you have two XspDocs on one page.  Both of them are new.  XspDoc could have a postSave event written in JavaScript that takes its UNID and puts it into the second XspDoc before saving that one too.  (I tend to be a fan of the quick and dirty)

Comment: default values are only calculated once in xpages on document open and never again.  It is the default value for the compenent, not the field.  If you save the document and expect the default values to pop up, you are in for a long wait.  Another option would be a computeWithForm call and calculating the field on the document level.  Such calculations should be done in a querySave, PostSave, or onChange function.  I also generally write my own javascript save routine where I call those functions myself and do not depend on the datasource events.

Comment: In that case, the field would have to be computed, not editable with a default value, and you have to make sure that you enabled the compute with form option in the properties of the datasource.  IF you call save by javascript, ensure that you have called computewithform directly. Also make sure that the component is being refreshed after the save.

Comment: <a href="http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesXSPDocument_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages#isNewNote"> This site has all of the needed stuff for working with XspDocs</a>  isNewNote() has worked for me in the past.  If you are having issues with it, I recommend a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If PDoc is available at the same level of the hierarchy as CDoc, e.g. both are datasources assigned to the XPage / Custom Control or the same Panel, you could update PDoc on save, using PDoc.replaceItemValue("txt_CompanieUNID",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID()). setValue should also work. Then you would not need the default value.

It just helps keep all business logic in one place. You could also check whether a value has already been set.

Comment: Pdoc is available only in a dialog which is open from a button from the xpage where Cdoc is defined. Btw, if there is a field binded to a form field which has as default formula @Text(@DocumentUNiqueId) than the field from xpage contains the Universal Id?

Comment: It *sounds* like you're loading the page, at which the Edit Box txt_CompanieUNID1 gets its default value set. You're then saving the document which gives it a UNID, but not updating txt_CompanieUNID1. So txt_CompanieUNID1 still has the old value. Even refreshOnShow will not work, because the default value is only set when the Edit Box is first loaded and doesn't have a value. If so, there are three options I can see. 1) Update the Edit Box. 2) Use a Computed Field control instead, bound to CDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID(). 3) Skip using the Edit Box and compute the value dynamically.

Comment: I used your 2) suggestion. The value is copied to the computed field from the dialog. BUT, I have a computed field too on my xpage where Cdoc is defined and the button which opens the dialog exists. When I'm creating an action=newDocument this computed field already have some UNID. When I hit the button ( its code is just showing the component ) this UNID changes ( automatically ) and in the dialog is added the old one.

Comment: In fact, to simplify: i just want to pass on the UNID of Cdoc into a field from a dialog. I already have a computed field value ( on the xpage where Cdoc is defined ) having the value: CDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID(). This value I want to pass on to some field from the dialog; the problem is when I show the dialog the field with CDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID() changes its value. I guess if I'm using Cdoc.computedField3 for the dialog field .. it won't work.

Comment: Is refreshOnShow property on Dialog control set to true? Otherwise, it's not updating its contents.

Comment: i added it now . Meanwhile, I found out that I must save my Cdoc and just after that to add the Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalId() to my computed field...

Comment: Yes. While CDoc is a new document, it will not have a valid ID. After save, it gets the ID. At that point you can use that ID and any computed components in the refresh area will now display that value. The Ext Lib dialog is essentially the Dojo dialog, so client-side, so is not intended to update its contents before displaying. That's done by refreshOnShow="true"