# xpages why my field value isn't copied correctly

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I add some time ago this question [xpages passing the UNID to other field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302109/xpages-passing-the-unid-to-other-field) ... and for the moment it seems it worked.

After I created the `<xe:dialog>` structure ( which uses a single datasource: `Pdoc` ), I observed I can't get the correct `UNID` of the other datasource: `Cdoc`. This dialog is showed from the xpages having the datasource `Cdoc.`

On the main Xpage ( which has as the datasource: `Cdoc`) there is a computed field: ( `txt_UNID` is on a form having the formula @text(@uniquedocumentid) )

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}"></xp:text>
```

and a button which shows the dialog:

```
<xp:button value="Adding a Pdoc structure inside my dialog" id="button3"
        styleClass="lotusFormButton" refreshMode="partial" rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField3">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript: if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save();
 Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
 getComponent('exampleDialog').show() }
 else
 {
Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()}
}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

The dialog is having the `refreshOnShow` set to `true`. Inside the dialog, there is a field ( binded to the `Pdoc` source ) where I want to display the UNID of `Cdoc` stored in the previous computed field from my main XPage:

```
                    <xp:inputText value="#{Pdoc.txt_CompanieUNID}"
                        id="inputText1" defaultValue="#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}">
                    </xp:inputText>
```

I think the problem is here ... Instead of `#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}`, I did tried adding `getComponent("computedField3").getValue()` as the default value for my above `inputText`, but I get an error, considering the fact, I suppose, the `computedField3` isn't inside the dialog ?
What am I doing wrong?

Btw, the dialog contains numerous fields ( binded to Pdoc ) having the default value:

```
Cdoc.<field_name>
```

and it works OK. I don't know why in the case of the `computedField3/txt_UNID` it doesn't work.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up field name and component name. Do this in your button that shows the dialog to update the field txt_UNID with the expected value:

```
Cdoc.setValue("txt_UNID", Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
```

Comment: I did add your suggestion in my button code. But, my problem ( as it says in the question title ) is I can't pass this value ( from computedField3 or txt_UNID ) to a field from the dialog. txt_UNID after showing the dialog has a value, and the field inside the dialog is having other value / UNID

Comment: Are you sure that Cdoc has a value in the txt_UNID field?

Comment: this field : <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{Cdoc.txt_UNID}"></xp:text> is visible so I can verify the value. And indeed after showing the dialog, this field contains a value / UNID.

Comment: And the field txt_UNID has the default formula: @Text(@DocumentUniqueID), laying on a form.

Comment: And you want that value in the Pdoc.txt_CompanieUNID field?

Comment: yes, which is inside the dialog. The dialog has only Pdoc  defined as datasource. I have numerous fields which I put the values from Cdoc just in the same way: Cdoc.(field_name) and it works OK.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value in the button event: Pdoc.setValue("txt_CompanieUNID", Cdoc.getValue("txt_UNID"))?

Comment: My XPage which contains the button has only Cdoc declared as the datasource. so I get an error: pdoc not found

Comment: The dialog has a onload event or something similar. Try to use that for setting the value.

Comment: I add in the onLoad event of the dialog : Pdoc.setValue("txt_CompanieUNID", Cdoc.getValue("txt_UNID")) , but it doesn't work. I recap my code and let you know ... hope to get it work

Comment: believe me or not , I just reopened the designer & the client and now it seems it works... I don't know why, I will accept your answer considering the fact that you helped me to set the value for the field name / not the component.